# How did this "guess the emoji" markup appear in the json response from my wordpress blog?

Tags: json, wordpress

I'm building an app using the json response from my personal blog, specifically this url:

http://www.johncorser.com/?json=1&count=15

if you examine the raw contents of that, it should be pure json (as wordpress promises json response at a url of this form).

However, instead of pure json, the json that I want is prepended with

```
<div style="position:absolute; margin-left:-9980em;">
<a href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-answers">94% cheats</a>
<a href="http://94prozent.net">94% prozent</a>
<a href="http://goldanswers.com">94% game answers</a>
<a href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-level-10-answers.html">94% level 10 answers</a>
<a href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-level-97-answers.html">94% level 97 answers</a>
<a title="94% Equipment used by Indiana Jones" href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-equipment-used-by-indiana-jones.html">94% Equipment used by Indiana Jones</a>
<a title="94% Something found in the living room" href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-something-found-in-the-living-room.html">94% Something found in the living room</a>
<a title="94% Couple" href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-couple.html">94% Couple</a>
<a href="http://guesstheemoji.org/94-answers">94 percent answers</a>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any information on this? It looks like I've been hacked but I cannot find the source of this to remove it, and it seems to only appear on the json response

Comment: This is a built in feature in 4.2.1. @ChristienCooper has done a complete post on this on WPSE

Comment: Please include the link you are referring to. I highly doubt anyone wouild consider this randomly injected markup to be  "feature"

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/185577/31545

Comment: Nice -although I'm not completely sure this is the same issue. I installed the suggested plugin at https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-emojis/ and the problem still exists. Also, these seem to be links to ads rather than just emoji support.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you have a Wordpress plugin installed:
**wp-includes/js/twemoji.min.js**
Some kind of emoji based plugin
If you didn't install this I would suggest removing all your plugins you haven't intended to install. Securing your passwords, and making sure your WP and Plugins are up to date.

Comment: This does not appear on my list of plugins. Is it hidden somehow?

Comment: Did you check wp-admin/network/plugins.php

if they are listed there If the plugins ARE listed there, go to http://example.com/wp-admin/network/settings.php - Scroll down to "Menu Settings" and see if the box to enable plugins is checked. IF NOT that's why the individual sites can't see plugins. Check that and you will allow users to activate plugins per site.

ONLY network activate plugins that absolutely, 100%, MUST be active on all sites. DO NOT EVER activate all your plugins network wide without thinking about it first

It is probably something that got installed with a theme you are using

Comment: I do not have sufficient permissions to view the page at `wp-admin/network/plugins.php`

Comment: Also, for my future knowledge, how did you find that wp-includes/js/twemoji.min.js was the culprit?

Comment: I'm not 100% that it is the culprit, it just looks a little suspicious when you're getting a bunch of guesstheemoji spam links and you have an emoji plugin installed. <br><br> I just inspected the Request URLs being sent from your site. Then checked the parameters for anything looking dodgy to see what it was up to